# Cassandra schema for authentication

Tags: database-design, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, datastax-astra

I am trying to design a database to store user information and to authenticate them.

My fields include **Name, email, password, phone number, city**.

How should I **partition my data** so that its efficient to authenticate them??

Comment: authentication by email? then just use it as partition key

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of handling this depending on your needs. We recommend you use a natural key such as email addresses since they are universally unique by default.

Here's a table schema that uses emails as the partition key:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    email text,
    name text,
    password text,
    phone text,
    city text,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
)
```

A variation is if you want users to be able to choose a username:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    username text,
    email text,
    name text,
    password text,
    phone text,
    city text,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

We recommend that you use Cassandra's compare-and-set (CAS) feature with [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html) (LWTs) using the conditional `IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS`. For example, to prevent overwriting details of existing users:

```
INSERT INTO users_by_email (...) VALUES (...) IF NOT EXISTS
```

```
INSERT INTO users_by_username (...) VALUES (...) IF NOT EXISTS
```

As a side note unrelated to the schema, we recommend for best practice that you encrypt user passwords before storing them in the database. Cheers!

Comment: Is it useful to use email as the partition key?? Wouldn't it create too many partitions??

Comment: Any natural key is useful and email addresses are used a lot in various Cassandra use cases since they are universally unique. You will have as many partitions as you have users. Cheers!